# App links do not work because of deep link intent-filter

Tags: android, deeplink, android-app-links

Imagine following `AndroidManifest.xml` ready to support app links:

```
 <activity ...>

            <!-- Intent filter specifying that this activity is a launcher activity -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Intent filter for an app link: https://www.example.com/books -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/books" />
            </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

So at this point app links are working: `assetlinks.json` is uploaded on the server, and when the user clicks in the browser on a link like: `https://www.example.com/books`, then the user is automatically taken into the app (without showing the app chooser dialog).

Now, at some point later we added support for deeplinks via push notifications: you get a notification via Firebase, tap on it, and start an `Intent` with the uri `https://com.application.package/books`. Some activity handles this intent and redirects the user to an appropriate screen.

Now the manifest looks like this:

```
 <activity ...>

            <!-- New intent filter to support 
                 deeplinks of type: https://com.application.package/books -->

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="false">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="com.application.package"
                    android:pathPrefix="/books"
                    android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>

            <!-- // the other 2 intent filters follow bellow.. -->

</activity>
```

As a result of this addition, we noticed that the app links stopped working (app chooser dialog was showing to the user), so after some trial and error investigation we found out that in fact, having these three declarations in the deeplink intent-filter, is what breaks the app links:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

If the above `<action />` and `<category ../>` tags are removed from the deep link intent-filter, then the app links start working again.
But, as a result, now the deep links no longer work, which in this case is expected, because we are using an SDK, and that SDK is specifically looking `.action.VIEW`.

Why adding this new intent-filter would cause the app links to stop working? Would appreciate any suggestions from your side.